Slowness in check style task after upgrade to gradle to 8.7
I have recently upgraded my gradle build to version 8.7. I can see it quite slow compare to our existing 6.6 builds. While doing profiling I fund that most of the time is spent in check style task. The time spent is increased from 1 min to 8 min in check style task.
I tried increasing memory given to check-style tasks but of no use. I read that there are some changes done around checkstyle task in version 7 to make it run in separate worker.
[https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/release-notes.html#checkstyle-tasks-use-toolchains-and-execute-in-parallel-by-default][1]
Is this a bug or there is any fix/workaround for this issue?
Checkstyle settings are

checkstyle {
        configFile = new File(projectDir, "config/MyCheckStyle.xml")
        configProperties.checkstyleConfigDir = configFile.parentFile

        toolVersion = 9.3 // we cant go above this as are on java 8
        checkstyleTest.enabled = false
        checkstyleIntTest.enabled = false
        ignoreFailures = false
        //logger.isEnabled(LogLevel.DEBUG)

    }

    tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
        it.logging.setLevelInternal(LogLevel.LIFECYCLE)
        //logging.captureStandardOutput(LogLevel.INFO) // print logs
        checkstyleMain.source = "src/main/java"
        exclude("**/generated/**")
        exclude("**/resources/**")
        exclude("**/intTest/**")
        //minHeapSize = "512m"
        maxHeapSize = "3g"
        reports {
            xml.required = false
            html.required = true
        }
    }


  [1]: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/release-notes.html#checkstyle-tasks-use-toolchains-and-execute-in-parallel-by-default

